# Installed Figaro, but can't see config/applicaton.yml in terminal

Tags: ruby, rubygems, figaro-ruby

So I put figaro into my Gem file and did a bundle install, but when I try to go to my config/application.yml file it is not there.  Any idea why it would download figaro and not install that file.  Also, this isn't the first time I have downloaded a Gem and files haven't been generated in Atom.  Not sure if am missing a step?  Please help, ruby newby.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your Gemfile so we have an idea of what the problem might be! Some more details in general would be helpful too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run `rails generate figaro:install` after you run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

terminal: figaro install , will create tour (yml) file.